# How to create recursive concurrent tree search in go

Tags: go, recursion, concurrency

Is there a proper way to implement concurrency inside recursive tree search in go?

The following code shows basic recursive tree search for a tree of nodes having id and children properties.
If I find a result I can close the channel but in case there is no result how to deal with that?

```golang
// Node is a struct containing int field ID and []*Node field Children.
type Node struct {
    ID       int
    Children []*Node
}

// Find search for a record by id inside an array of records
func Find(node *Node, id int) *Node {

    if node.ID == id {
        return node
    }

    for _, c := range node.Children {
        found := Find(c, id)
        if found != nil {
            return found
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: you will close the channel in both case to signal end of search.

Comment: If I close the channel, will the other go routines stop?

Comment: that depends of the code ? I cant tell.

Comment: @mh-cbon I posted a possible solution in answers. But I still think it is missing something because it keeps opening go routines even after finding the solution.

Comment: yes, your implementation starts a goroutine for each branch of your tree, thus if it enters a branch that does not contain the value, it will browse it until the end. further more, writing a closed channel is an error. Plus, spawning that many goroutine is not  efficient. In your pseudo code you are closing the channel to signal a value was found. What happens f the value exists twice ? Does finding the value necessarily means you have ended to browse the tree ?

Comment: Good points @mh-cbon. I thought that the select at the beginning of the function will force other goroutines to terminate. Is there a possible way to do it?
Plus, why spawning too many goroutines is not efficient? I thought creating goroutines will make compute faster. I am looking for a good implementation for a similar problem. Do you know a good example or how to refactor my code?

Comment: this is not a trivial problem, that is, i believe, one of the reason you are receiving no help. Having muliple goroutine can improve the speed of an algorithm under some circumstances, it might be harmfull under other circumstances. the more routines you spawn the more pressure you put on the runtime to handle the context switching, go is certainly capale of handling Zillions of routines in parallel, but it comes with a cost. You must always weight the costs and benefits. In your pseudo code spawning a routine to perform a comparison is not good.

Comment: thinking of your problem some questions i have are, how to detect the end of search, how to partition the tree, how to prevent stupid performance pitfall in some edge cases, and overall, is it really worthy ? non concurrent programming is extremely fast and efficient to execute.

Comment: `Is there a possible way to do it?`. Yes. Many ways. is it always a win ? Can it be done with such simple data structure ? less clear.

Comment: I strongly recommnd you to search, view and learn from the many online conferences given by go authors and professional to learn more before continuing.

Comment: Thansk for your advice and your feedback @mh-cbon. I started learning golang and I am trying many things. Knowing that concurrency is not the suitable solution in the way I presented is a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple and stupid benchmark that i hope will be helpful to OP to better understand impacts of simplistic implementations of concurrent programming.

```golang
package main_test

import (
    "sync"
    "testing"
)

func SearchNonConcurrently(v int, mySlice []int) int {
    for idx, i := range mySlice {
        if i == v {
            return idx
        }
    }
    return -1
}

func SearchConcurrently(v int, mySlice []int) int {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(len(mySlice))
    res := make(chan int)
    for idx, i := range mySlice {
        go func(idx, i int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            if i == v {
                res <- idx
            }
        }(idx, i)
    }
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(res)
    }()
    idx, ok := <-res
    if !ok {
        return -1
    }
    return idx
}

func BenchmarkSearchNonConcurrently(b *testing.B) {
    mySlice := make([]int, 10000)
    mySlice[len(mySlice)-1] = 1
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        SearchNonConcurrently(1, mySlice)
    }
}

func BenchmarkSearchConcurrently(b *testing.B) {
    mySlice := make([]int, 10000)
    mySlice[len(mySlice)-1] = 1
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        SearchConcurrently(1, mySlice)
    }
}
```

The results:

```sh
$ go test -bench=. -benchmem -count=4
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
pkg: test/bencslice
BenchmarkSearchNonConcurrently-4       85780         13831 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkSearchNonConcurrently-4       83619         13880 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkSearchNonConcurrently-4       87128         14050 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkSearchNonConcurrently-4       87366         13837 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
BenchmarkSearchConcurrently-4            235       4867257 ns/op        2200 B/op          6 allocs/op
BenchmarkSearchConcurrently-4            244       4896937 ns/op        3360 B/op          8 allocs/op
BenchmarkSearchConcurrently-4            240       4871934 ns/op         453 B/op          2 allocs/op
BenchmarkSearchConcurrently-4            244       4884617 ns/op        3352 B/op          8 allocs/op
PASS
ok      test/bencslice  12.087s
$ go version
go version go1.15.2 linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the follwing code. My only regret is that it keeps creating go routines even after finding the solution. I mean for a sorted tree with 1000 elements if I search for node with `ID = 5` it keeps opening cases with above 900.

```golang
func FindConcurrent(node *Node, id int, c chan *Node) {
    select {
    case <-c:
        return
    default:
    }

    if node.ID == id {
        c <- node
        close(c)
        return
    }

    for _, child := range node.Children {
        go FindConcurrent(child, id, c)
    }

}
```